# How do I configure nginx to have a server block pointing towards a django app?

Tags: nginx, unix, django, fastcgi

Suppose I have an nginx server, with Django apps set up as "/djangoapps/exampleapp1/" and "/djangoapps/exampleapp2/".

Suppose I just registered a domain "www.exampleapp2.com".

How can I point www.exampleapp2.com to my django app?

From reading the nginx docs, it seems like it would be fairly straightforward if I were only serving static files. Once I throw in the Django, though, it becomes difficult.

My nginx config would look something like this:

```
server {
    server_name www.exampleapp2.com;
    location / {
        # What do I put here?
    }
}

server {
    root   /var/www;

    location /djangoapps {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^()(.*)$;
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you try ? What are your observations or your difficulties ?